# How to Render and get input in multiple windows SFML and GLFW?

Tags: opengl, sfml, glfw, imgui

I want to create two or more windows with a mix of SFML and GLFW since that GLFW supports multi-monitors.
I achieved rendering in two windows but the input is locked until I close one of both. I'm using ImGui to show buttons and options, and SFML to render the close, minimize and maximize buttons. The only thing that receives input is those buttons but only in the main window. What I do is the next:

1. Create a GLFW window.
2. Integrate SFML via Win32 to that window.
3. Begin ImGui in the window and show a button to create the second window.
4. I press the button and the input is locked after creating the new window.
5. I close the second window and the main return to normality.

[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4DKj.png)

[Second Wndow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwddV.png)

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use both SFML and GLFW in the same application. They both do more or less the same thing, so they tend to step on each others' toes.

Comment: GLFW supports monitors and SFML handles the windows easier to render. I prefer SFML but I need multiple monitors and the ways I tried to render with GLFW just doesn't work.